# Finding out existing Geofences from LocationServices.GeofencingApi

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

I have an app where I am setting up a couple of geofencing using the LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofence() method. When the app is restarted, is there a way I can get the existing set of GeoFence which I have added and then add only if they are missing? How do I get the current list of Geofences my app has added?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get those values out of LocationServices.GeofencingApi.

Comment: how would one do it? There has to be someway I would imagine to remove an existing fence.. otherwise the brute force way is remove everything, and then add a new set with updated contents.. but that sounds so hacky

Comment: What's your question then? I see the title "Finding out existing Geofences from LocationServices.GeofencingApi" - this is not possible. If this is not your question then ask it differently.

Answer (score -2):

You can check geofence list every time before setting geofences this code may help you.

```
public void populateGeofenceList() {
            for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                String[] values = key.split(",");
                mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                        // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                        // geofence.
                        .setRequestId(values[0])
                                // Set the circular region of this geofence.
                        .setCircularRegion(
                                entry.getValue().latitude,
                                entry.getValue().longitude,
                                Float.parseFloat(values[1])
                        )
                                // Set the expiration duration of the geofence. This geofence gets automatically
                                // removed after this period of time.
                        .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                                // Set the transition types of interest. Alerts are only generated for these
                                // transition. We track entry and exit transitions in this sample.
                        .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                                // Create the geofence.
                        .build());
            }
            for(Geofence g:mGeofenceList) {
                Log.i("Geofences Array",g.toString());
            }

        }
```

Comment: Isn't the code above adding the geofences? I am looking for once you have added the fences for the app, a subsequent launch of the app needs to figure out what has been previously added.